# Ruby: Benefits of putting my code inside a Module?

Tags: ruby

What's the benefit of putting all my methods inside a Module?

```
module Math
  def Math.print_message
    puts "Testing 123 ..."
  end
end
```

If I just write "print_message" in the file and then require the file from within another file, then I can call "print_message" as well.

What's the advantage of having it within this Module-end construct?

Comment: It allows you to organize your code (group all math related methods in one module) and to namespace your methods (so you can have `Math.log` and `Logger.log` without any problems).

Comment: @Stefan Makes sense. If you like: Turn your comment into an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Some Things a Ruby [Module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Module.html) Can Do for You

In many ways, modules act a lot like classes, although you can't actually instantiate them. There are quite a number of reasons to put code, classes, and other objects inside modules. These include:

1. Namespacing, to prevent collisions between same-named constants, classes, methods, and variables.
2. The ability to compose or extend classes, rather than relying on Ruby's single-inheritance model by "mixing in" modules. That's why modules in Ruby are often called mixins.
3. The ability define class and module level methods that don't need to be instantiated to be used.
4. The ability to hook the inclusion of modules to create certain behavior when you mix them into other classes.
5. Support for [autoloading](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Module.html#method-i-autoload).
6. The ability to adjust the lookup order of the class hierarchy depending on whether you include or [prepend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Module.html#method-i-prepend) a module.
7. Support for refinements (see [Module#refine](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Module.html#method-i-refine) and [Module#using](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Module.html#method-i-using)).

There are likely other things that I haven't thought about in this quick, off-the-cuff answer. However, modules are essential building blocks for gems and larger Ruby applications, and understanding them is worth doing, especially if you're planning to grow beyond basic scripting with Ruby.